# How do I detect the "new" modifer on a field using reflection?

Tags: .net, reflection

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/435f1dw2.aspx

```
public class Base
{
    public string Field;
}
public class Child : Base
{
    public new string Field;
}

[TestFixture]
public class TestClass
{

    [Test]
    public void DetectNew()
    {
        var fieldInfo = typeof(Child).GetField("Field");
        //How do I tell fieldInfo has a new modifier?
        Debug.WriteLine(fieldInfo);
    }
}
```

**Edit:** I know for Methods and Properties I can check "MethodBase.IsHideBySig". Why doesnt a similar property exist for FieldInfo?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Just a guess, but I think you'd have to search the base-class(es) for a *member* with the same name.

You could also take a look at the generated IL for both fields to see if there're any differences that you can use through reflection.

Comment: This is the approach I was hoping to avoid.

Comment: I took a look at ILSpy's source code, they are doing the same thing - walking the inheritance chain. They are using Mono.Cecil, but there is no special info that's unavailable via reflection. For more information, take a look at ILSpy's `AstBuilder.SetNewModifier` method.

Answer (score 1):

The only effect of `new` here is to suppress a compiler warning.

My guess would be that it leaves no trace in the generated IL.

Counter question: Why are you interested? Just curious or do you have a practical scenario?

Comment: "new here is to suppress a compiler warning"?? but this is not the case for Methods and Properties. I can check "MethodBase.IsHideBySig".
Why is it different for fields?

Comment: "fields can never be virtual" true. however I am still surprised that I can add an modifier to a field and have exactly the same IL generated.

Comment: But minus a warning. The docs talk about 'intent'.  I found the IsHideBySig/NewSlot differences more surprising.

Comment: as for why I want to do it... so in XAML I can bind to fields and still support INotifyPropertyChanged http://snipt.org/xltp