# How to determine if a field has 'new' modifier via reflection?

Tags: c#, reflection

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [How do I detect the "new" modifer on a field using reflection?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6634303/how-do-i-detect-the-new-modifer-on-a-field-using-reflection)

Having the following declaration

```
public class B : A
{
    public new string Name;
}
```

how do i determine if the field has 'new' modifier for its `FieldInfo` instance?

Comment: you really shouldn't expose fields like this... use a property instead.

Comment: also you should just set the value, not create a new reference.

Comment: @Daniel: new in this case means don't use the one in the base class

Comment: Correct - but fields shouldn't be exposed this way in the first place...

Comment: I didn't ask for best design practice. I need this to fix custom reflection-based serializer which fails at the moment for cases like in the sample.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I think you'll need to search the base-classes hierarchy for a member with the same name, and if it isn't, then it is new.

I know it's ugly, but as per the comment on this other answer to the same question [How do I detect the "new" modifer on a field using reflection?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6634303/how-do-i-detect-the-new-modifer-on-a-field-using-reflection/6634323#6634323), it says:

> I took a look at ILSpy's source code, they are doing the same thing -
>   walking the inheritance chain. They are using Mono.Cecil, but there is
>   no special info that's unavailable via reflection. For more
>   information, take a look at ILSpy's `AstBuilder.SetNewModifier` method.

Probably not what you have been expecting, sorry for that.

Comment: Yes, i expected something like FieldInfo.IsNew but your solution sounds like a way to go. Thanks!

Answer (score 10):

For fields, no such exists; the IL is simply:

```
.field public string Name
```

etc - since there is no concept of virtual fields or newslot etc. The `new` modifier here exists *purely* for the compiler, for you to assert that you *acknowledge* you are doing something a little bit confusing. Adding the `new` here will suppress a compiler warning (CS0108), but *does not change the IL*. As such, you cannot distinguish between a *formally* `new`d field vs a field that has been hidden without `new`.

It would be preferable, though, if you limited yourself to private fields with public accessor properties. And note that in either event: the field in the base type **still exists**.